# Strange brackets layout in RTL text direction region

Tags: html, right-to-left

The following html snippet

```
<div dir="rtl">
    test (test)
</div>
```

shows

```
(test (test
```

in all browsers.

Why?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741522/brackets-displays-wrongly-for-right-to-left-display-style ?

Comment: @Adrian Ber No, that question has been asked 1 year later. Thank you for pointing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**dir="rtl"** relates to the presentation of certain languages that go from right to left. According to this http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html website you should use logical characters instead of visual characters if you are wanting the same visual effect seen in the LTR view.