# brackets displays wrongly for right to left display style

Tags: html, google-chrome, right-to-left

The html code

```
<html dir="rtl">
<p>hello (world)</p>
</html>
```

you will see a page like this:

```
(hello (world
```

However，if I change the html code into

```
<html dir="rtl">
<p>hello (world) again</p>
</html>
```

Then the text displays normally:

```
 hello (world) again
```

Anyone can explain why this happens? 
How to fix the first example?

My browser is chrome

Comment: this one is hard ... sorry for not having a solution here but for a very nice overview of lots of problems that can occur when changing reading direction I can recommend this link: http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "\[x\]y" display incorrectly in the RTL direction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973319/why-does-xy-display-incorrectly-in-the-rtl-direction)

Answer (score 46):

You just need to add the LRM character after the last bracket. HTML entity: `&#x200E;`

```
<html dir="rtl">
<body>
<p>hello (world)&#x200E;</p>
</body></html>
```

This tells the browser to interpret the brackets as left-to-right reading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801820/how-to-solve-bidi-bracket-problem/7931735#7931735), these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: When I see an answer, I don't really expect it to have been handwritten by the user. Many times it's not even practical (although a backlink might be useful for further info). While using this tip I found it Chrome developer tools a nice shorthand `&lrm;` - easier to remember...

Comment: I was searching for this solution from long. `&#x200E;` worked for me very well. Thanks :)

Comment: @freeworlder This is not working with "placeholder" attribute in "input" tag.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 17):

Or better you can try in CSS

```
*:after {
    content: "\200E‎";
}
```

Comment: This did nothing for me. The parenthesis are still wrong but it did insert random gaps everywhere.

Comment: Yeah works here, I'd make sure the style is actually being applied to your elements

Comment: @Adrian This is not working with "placeholder" attribute in "input" tag.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the special rlm character in css before and after your element solved all cases I've come across in Firefox and Chrome:

```
*:after {
    content: "\200E‎";
}
*:before {
    content: "\200E‎";
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `&rlm;` before `(`.
Ex:

```
<html dir="rtl">
<body>
<p>hello &rlm;(world)</p>
</body></html>
```

if you are using javascript/svg Dom then

```
 aText = $('<span>').html(aText.replace("(","&rlm;(")).text();
 $("<p>").html(aText);
```

for other special Charactors

```
function getRTLText(aText,aChar) {
        if ( aText != undefined && aText.replace){
            aChar = (aChar === undefined )?"(":aChar;
            aText = $('<span>').html(aText.replace(aChar,"&rlm;"+aChar)).text();
        }
        return aText;
}
```

and call function

`getRTLText("March / 2018","/");`

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct bracket rendering for right to left text (apparently). This article gives a bit more info.

http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html

<del>The `dir` attribute is now depreciated.</del>

Answer (score -1):

If anyone has this issue in WordPress you can try this fix:

https://gist.github.com/dtbaker/b532e0e84a8cb7f22f26

```
function dtbaker_rtl_bracket_hack($content){
    if(is_rtl()){
        $content = preg_replace('#<p>([^<]+)\)\s*</p>#','<p>$1)&#x200E;</p>',$content);
        $content = preg_replace('#<p>\s*\(([^<]+)</p>#','<p>&#x200E;($1</p>',$content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','dtbaker_rtl_bracket_hack',100,1);
```

Comment: Using sledgehammers to crack nuts.