# Align bullet points to the right instead of left

Tags: html, css

I have bullet points that are aligned right and I would like the bullet points to appear on the right instead of left.

I'm using bullet points because I will replace the bullet with an arrow the points to a URL and use it for navigation.

How do I do this?

This is the code that i'm using for the navigation in the header:

```
.header right {
padding-top: 8px;
float: right;
text-align: right;
}
.header right ul
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.header right a
{
display:block;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

and the html

```
<right>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Jewel Thieves</a></li>
<li><a href="">Community</a></li>
</ul>
</right>
```

If I use direction rtl, the bullets dissapeared.

Comment: post Html too..so that we can make a fiddle

Comment: @Anthony "If I use direction rtl, the bullets disappeared" ?? no they don't.you probably have some other css that is causing the bullets to disappeare

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLh0q2ud/)

**MARK UP:**

```
<div dir="rtl">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Jewel Thieves</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Community</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `div` container and CSS declarations block (in JSFiddle) are unnecesary.

Answer (score 18):

Setting `direction: rtl` on the list element would put the bullets on the right, but this is fragile, since the setting also sets the overall writing direction. This means that e.g. “foo (bar)” will be displayed as “(foo (bar”, as per the Unicode bidirectional algorithm.

To deal with this, you need to set the direction to left-to-right inside the list items. In the special case that you might have here, each `li` contains just an `a` element and nothing more. Then the following would work:

```
<style>
ul { direction: rtl; }
ul li a { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: embed; }
</style>
```

However, this is probably too tricky. It is better to append the list markers (bullets, arrows, whatever) as characters or as images, possibly with CSS, to the list items and omit browser-generated list markers. The details depend on the specifics and context of the original problem.

Comment: 1+ Nice catch, everyone else failed to mention this.

Comment: ul li *{...} is even better

Comment: You just need to add the LRM character after the last bracket. HTML entity: &#x200E; as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741522/brackets-displays-wrongly-for-right-to-left-display-style)

Comment: Please give an example of images on the list items that align correctly on the right of the contents - I believe it is NOT trivial

Answer (score 14):

you can use `direction:rtl;` css property

or `dir="rtl"` html attribute

Comment: @Anthony this works perfectly. No issues in this and it is ridiculous you marked an answer that has nonexistent HTML tag <right>

Comment: Not robust. Check what happens if you have `<li><a href="...">foo?</a></li>` for example.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela so what should be done to avoid this??

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What is not robust? Please elaborate

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian `<li><a href="...">foo?&#x200E;</a></li>` will work

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela ul li *{direction:ltr}

Answer (score 3):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

<ul dir="rtl">
    <li>Write this text right-to-left</li>
    <li>Write this text right-to-left</li>
    <li>Write this text right-to-left</li>
</ul>

    </body>
    </html>
```

It will work for you

Answer (score 3):

Works for me

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/PxMf4/)

```
ul {
 direction:rtl;
 list-style-image:url(http://australianetwork.com/img/icon_arrow_left_black.png);   
}
```

Using simple and valid - note the entity `&#x200E;` on the right bracket and questionmark

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home (on the range)&#x200E; </a></li>
  <li><a href="">Jewel Thieves</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">foo?&#x200E;</a></li>
</ul>
```