# How to start unordered list bullet points from the right and separate colors for bullets and texts?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
toto -
roto -
moto -
```

but what I got so far is:

```
- toto
- moto
- roto
```

how to achieve this in plain css and html?
And how to have separate colors for bullet points and texts?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058885/align-bullet-points-to-the-right-instead-of-left

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align bullet points to the right instead of left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058885/align-bullet-points-to-the-right-instead-of-left)

Comment: um, yes and no. how to have separate colors for bullet points and texts?

Comment: If the lenghts of the texts in the li elements differ how do you want things align. Are the bullets to be one above the other or are the left hand sides of the texts to be above each other, and where is the whole list to sit in relation to its container? CSS ::marker pseudo element may help you but it depends on th alignment requirement.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm not sure what you mean exactly, I just had some random list in Arabic which, by default starts sentences from the right.. so I needed a way to start bullets from the right side with separate color of text and bullet. For now, things are working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vikneysh mentioned,

```
<ul dir="rtl">
```

is the right way to align it, and the only thing that worked for me for changing colors of those right aligned bullet points were:

```
ul {
  list-style: none; 
}

ul li::before {
  content: "-"; 
  color: red; /* Change the color */
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em; 
  margin-right: -1em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style your Unordered list as

```
 <style>ul { direction: rtl; }</style>
```

or just use the dir="rtl" attribute value

```
<ul dir="rtl">
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: how to have separate colors for bullet and text?

Comment: @ToveC. Try removing the default style of the bullet and define your own, i.e) try this out ul {list-style: none}
        li::before {content: "\2022"; color: red}

Comment: \2022 is the unicode for a round bullet point. If you want to use a hyphen as you did specify in your question, use content:"-";  Does this help?

Comment: It wasn't aligning right so I changed margin-right

Comment: Great! Happy it was somewhat useful.