# RTL Format numeric and symbols not align properly

Tags: php, html, css

I faced the RTL Alignment issue in numeric, Symbols and English character with inside the Arabic sentence. I attached the my screen in below.

In this image pink color marked is Arabic view and green border is English version. In this part Order number mentioned inside the brace (). It's perfect view in English (#ODiT27167979008), But in Arabic (#ODiT27167979008) . How to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: body {direction:rtl !important;} Just I add code in css. and Body dir="rtl"

Comment: OK see my answer for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets act kind of strangely when using rtl. Look here for more info: [brackets displays wrongly for right to left display style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741522/brackets-displays-wrongly-for-right-to-left-display-style)

But basically you need to add the LRM character after the last bracket ‎

```
<p class="rtl">(#ODiT27167979008)&#x200E;</p>
```