# Why does "[x]y" display incorrectly in the RTL direction?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

```html
<div style="direction: rtl">
[x]y
</div>
```

You can see HTML text `[x]y` displays as `x]y]`.

What is the reason of that result?

PS: I get that result in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Comment: Can you add information on the browser? It does work fine for me (displays [x]y). I tested it via the SO HTML feature and in a .html file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [brackets displays wrongly for right to left display style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741522/brackets-displays-wrongly-for-right-to-left-display-style)

Comment: @printxdiv0 I'm using chrome.

Comment: On firefox, I see `y[x]`

Comment: @Kroltan that's still wrong. Weird.

Comment: I've tried on my PC and see that Edge and Firefox display as `y[x]`, Vivaldi and Chrome display as `x]y]`

Comment: @Sam This question seems to have better answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is rendered correctly, i.e. according to specifications. You have asked for right-to-left layout. The rendering first takes the `[` character. It is directionally neutral and therefore rendered in a RTL run rightmost and mirrored (so it looks like `]`). Next, to the left of it comes `x]y` in that order, since the Latin letters `x` and `y` have inherent left-to-right directionality and the neutral `]` gets its directionality from them.
The conclusions to be drawn depends on the rendering you want and your reasons for using right-to-left directionality.

Comment: Nice explanation, but why `[x]` rendered as `[x]` (which is not `x]]`) according to your answer? Check that result by this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhfcrjr8/).

Comment: Sayakiss, in “[x]” there is nothing that prevents the brackets from deviating RTL layout, so it is rendered all right to left, with the bracket glyphs mirrored. You can see this if you set e.g. `<font color=red>[</font>`. It's the rightmost character that turns red; it is mirrored so that it looks like “]”. Similarly, the leftmost character is “]” rendered with a “[” glyph.

Comment: "Next, to the left of it, comes “x]y”, in that order, since the Latin letters “x” and “y” have inherent left-to-right directionality and the neutral “]” gets its directionality from them." My question is, why "x]y" have inherent left-to-right directionality, but "x]" does not?

Comment: Because in the former case the "neutral" character is *between* LTR characters. So it gets treated as LTR. In the latter case this doesn't apply.

Comment: Was `so it looks like “[”` supposed to say `so it looks like “]”`?

Comment: Yes, ‘so it looks like “[”’ was meant to refer to “]”; I’ll fix it.

Answer (score 34):

I cannot tell you the reason but I can tell you how to fix it: add `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;`. See [more](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_unicode-bidi.asp) about it

```html
<div style="direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">
[x]y
</div>
```

The description

> The unicode-bidi property is used together with the direction property to set or return whether the text should be overridden to support multiple languages in the same document.

is not clear enough to explain the behaviour. However, it works.

EDIT

[The MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) brings some light here, `bidi-override` actually disables the browser standard smart behaviour and everything works as is / as expected.

Comment: unicode-bidi on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi)

Comment: Honestly, the "why" is secondary to getting the perceived problem fixed (in this stack). Another answer tells the why, but this should be the proper answer IMHO. I get that the question is a poor fit to the site, but +1 to this answer.

Answer (score 17):

After some research, I found [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7931678/5178016) info: [Right-To-Left text direction](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html)

> Parentheses and square brackets do not have an inherent direction. The open parenthesis is between LTR and RTL text runs and so cannot "inherit" the direction of the surrounding text. It therefore defaults to the RTL base direction of the paragraph and is placed to the left of the Hebrew word shalom. Note the closing square bracket is embedded in a single run of left-to-right text. It therefore adopts the direction of its surrounding text and is placed to the right of the English word shalom.

Answer (score 2):

one of the solutions is to add **`&#x200e;`** after the bracket

thanks to @freeworlder for the solution on
[brackets displays wrongly for right to left display style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741522/brackets-displays-wrongly-for-right-to-left-display-style)

even you can use other char, follow this link
http://www.codetable.net/hex/200e

Answer (score 0):

Try using an open square bracket "[" where you need a closed square bracket, and vice versa. I had a font with a letter mapped to "[" and it would not display. I changed the letter in the database to "]" and it worked.

Comment: Having an issue using the > bracket in this html rtl document
https://ilmlc.sourceforge.io/books/multilinear_torah/html/multilinear_torah_3rd_edition_4_fonts.html

The Aramaic font estrangelo_cursive (the second line from the top) uses the > keystroke for letter equal to the hebrew letter kaf. 
The last letter of the last word in line one shows up fine, but on line three, the eighth word from the right the > ends up at the end of the word.
Tried  >, &#x003c;, &lsaquo;. The html sees the > and flips the order of words that begin with >.
My try remapping the font keystroke

Comment: changing the > angle to &#x003c;&#x200E; in the mysql database corrected the problem