# Strange behaviour with direction: rtl and closing braces at the end of the sentence

Tags: css

I have some text with a braced part at the end and the containing div has the Css property `direction: rtl;`. This causes the closing brace to appear at the beginning of the sentence as opening brace.

So

```
Some text with (braces)
```

becomes

```
(Some text with (braces
```

```css
#strange-behaviour {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="strange-behaviour">
  Some text with (braces)
</div>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sec47h7v/).

**My question**

How can I motivate the closing brace to stay the closing brace?

Comment: Seems fine on FF, but chrome and safari are no good. Looks like a bug, but already answered on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [brackets displays wrongly for right to left display style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741522/brackets-displays-wrongly-for-right-to-left-display-style)

Comment: @Huangism somehow a duplicate. Ujnimz answer fits my problem a bit more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add LRM character after the last bracket:

```css
#strange-behaviour {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="strange-behaviour">
  Some text with (braces)&lrm;
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But I prefer using `&lrm;` because of better readability.